# File extensions and C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am new to C# and ASP.NET and I am trying to read the files from a directory in order to display them on a page. The issue that I am running into is that the files that I am trying to read are from a proprietary phone recording software and the files do not have an extension, hence when I am trying to read the files in the directory using Directory.GetFiles(directoryName) I get nothing in return as if the directory is empty. However when I use a different directory where files have extensions I am able to get the list of the files.

Any ideas?

Code sample

```
string path = "C:\\Users\\directoryName";

foreach (string filename in Directory.GetFiles(path))
{
 FileInfo file = new FileInfo(filename);
 string name = file.Name;
 Response.Write(name);
}
```

Thank you in advance for any help provided.

Comment: Have you tried `Directory.GetFiles(path,"*.")`?
`

Comment: Are you sure your path is correct? even when you do not specify a pattern I am able to get all files with a simple `var g = Directory.GetFiles("c:\\00\\10\\01");`

Answer (score 3):

I was a little skeptical that it wouldn't work on extensionless files. So I've tried the code you provided in a console application on a test directory with extensionless files. It works fine for me, I don't believe that the fact it doesn't have an extension is the issue.

I would check that the directory is correct, that IIS (that application pool account of your application) has permission to access the files in the directory and there are files in that directory.

Comment: Hello everyone, I am working on my local machine and the directory has files and the correct permissions. Also IIS has the correct settings on the directory. I copied the same files and added the extension that it gives in the documentation for the phone software and then it worked, but the issue is that the application is not going to work on the files with extensions. I guess I can make a copy of the files, put them in a different location and add the extension prior to working with them.

Comment: So you are saying that your version of the .NET BCL doesn't do the same as what mine does and the documentation on MSDN for .net 2.0 to 4.0 is also wrong? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07wt70x2.aspx

Answer (score 1):

```
Use Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.*")
```

Comment: it will search for . in the file name.

Comment: Tilak, you are wrong. it will return all files whether they have . or not.

Comment: my mistake. I thought it as a Regex, and not a Search Pattern

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get only files that have no extension you can do the following:

```
        foreach (String sFile in Directory.GetFiles("PATH", "*."))
        {
            Responce.Write(System.IO.Path.GetFileName(sFile));
        }
```

I also agree with Chris, IIS might not have permissions to access the directory to list the files.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Directory.GetFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz42302f) overload to include all the files.

```
Directory.GetFiles(path, "*")
```

Comment: Does this work? The [`Directory.GetFiles(string path)` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07wt70x2.aspx) notes: _"This method is identical to GetFiles with the asterisk (*) specified as the search pattern."_.